# How to process 2 forms in a single html page using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 forms in a single html page. The first form is for logging in and the other is for signing up.

The login form contains a submit button with a `name="loginsubmit"` attribute while the signup form contains a submit button with a `name="signupbutton"` attribute.

How can I detect which submit button was clicked with jQuery so that I can pass it off to PHP?

Comment: only 1 form can be submitted one at a time, and by checking `$_POST` array you know which form and field are submitted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try understanding this.

```
<form action="check_login.php" method="POST">
    ....// form elements
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN" />
</form>


<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    ....// form elements
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="REGISTER" />
</form>
```

When you have 2 separate forms, change their action. As simple as that.
If flow comes to `check_login.php`, the click is on login button.If flows comes to `register.php`, then click is on register.

**Note:**

Suppose if the action of both the form is same, add the following code in form action file.

```
  if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
      // click is on login button
  }


  if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
      // click is on register button
  }
```